# how install web server on a local machine (windows 7 or server 2008) for an asp.net web application?

Tags: iis, web-server, asp.net, localhost

i designed and developed a web application (works as a windows application) in asp.net with c# ...
now i want to use this application on a local machine instead of previous windows application !
how can i install web server on a local machine (windows 7 or server 2008) for an asp.net web application?
is iis necessary or not ?
if yes where can i find it for windows 7 and how can i fonfigure it for both windows 7 and server 2008?

thanks in advance

Comment: is any body home ? did i ask this Q in the right place?

Comment: They may be a StackOverflow question, but let me see if I understand.  You previously developed this as a winforms app and now you're creating a new version for the web.  It works within Visual Studio (I assume) and you're looking for a way to host it so that people can view it from a browser.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes , this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hosting it for external access, IIS the way to go (99% of people do that on a Windows computer).  You can add it in Windows 7 from Programs and Features -> Turn Windows Features on or off -> Internet Information Services.

Once you install it then edit your Default Web Site and point it to your project root folder.  Now browse to http://localhost or http://computer_name_or_ip.

Comment: thanks for answer / but how can i have many projects with different names -> we only have http://localhost or http://computer_name_or_ip. would be appreciate for help me about this -> i posted this issue in many places without any answer ...

Comment: Hi LostLord.  You can host multiple sites on the same server by using host headers and DNS entries.  You can enter a host header to bind to a unique binding.  Here's a video series of mine that covers a few topics that will help you in this endeavor.  Week 5 covers the bindings.  Week 2 covers DNS zones.  http://dotnetslackers.com/projects/LearnIIS7/

Comment: dear @Scott Forsyth - MVP : thanks for comment -> your movies are fantastic ... but i still do n't know how can i have multiple web sites working on localhost(127.0.0.1) ... one of my web sites is Test (D:\Test\Default.htm) and the other one is Test2 (D:\Test 2\Default.htm ... as you said in your movie we can put the HostName blank and edit hosts file (but is it necessary about my purpose? mean is there any way without editing this file?) , but we only have one ip (127.0.0.1) for local (which ips should i set for both of them?)  thanks in advance