# How to "edit your default website" in IIS?

Tags: iis

As per the answer in the following question: [how install web server on a local machine (windows 7 or server 2008) for an asp.net web application?](https://serverfault.com/questions/288777/)
"edit your Default Web Site and point it to your project root folder"

I do not see any option to edit my Default Web Site in IIS. How do I do it?

Comment: I figured this out. Open the 'Sites' folder in the 'Connections' pane. The choose 'Basic Settings'  from the 'Actions' pane on the right. From here you can set the physical root directory.

Comment: Yeah, I believe on IIS 6/7.x on a workstation (XP/Vista/7) it's limited to only one site.

Comment: @HorseloverFat if you resolve your own question, please provide the solution always as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 7.x IIS:

Open the 'Sites' folder in the 'Connections' pane. The choose 'Basic Settings' from the 'Actions' pane on the right. From here you can set the physical root directory.

Answer (score 2):

That would be just setting the Home Directory properties of the default web site so it points to the directory you want it to point to instead of the usual default. The actual steps to do this vary depending on which version of IIS you are running.

Answer (score 2):

The question refers to setting the project root folder or web site root, which is known as Physical Path in IIS 7 (Windows 7 or Windows 2008) or Local path in IIS 6 (Windows 2003 or Windows XP)

In IIS 6 the setting is on the Home Directory tab of the Default Web Site properties window in IIS Manager.

To set the Physical Path in IIS 7 or 7.5, open IIS Manager, select the Default Web Site and then follow the  Basic Settings... link on the Actions pane down the right, underneath the Edit Site heading.

Answer (score 0):

for me only this worked: click on Default Website > Manage websites > Advanced Settings > Change Application Pool to the new application